# Array of strings memory reallocation in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, realloc

I have a project to do and I need to reallocate the memory for the array. I tried many times, but I have found just one version that works.

```
void resize(int* size, char*** arr)
{
    *size *= 2;
    *arr = realloc(*arr, sizeof(char*) * *size);
    nulltest(*arr);    // This checks if the allocation was successful
}
```

```
resize(&size, &arr);
```

This function doubles the capacity of the array, but I think it's done too complicated, so I want to ask you guys, if this can be simplified or not. I'm open to new solutions too.

Comment: What do you mean by simplified? This is three lines of code in the implementation and one line of code to use, how much simpler do you need it?

Comment: This function only does one thing - introduces errors. Is bad and not needed

Comment: Yeah, I agree, I would just call `realloc` directly, but arguably that makes it less simple because you do need to do the new size calculation and error checking everywhere instead of inside the function. (I also give the benefit of the doubt and assume that `nulltest` crashes the program on failure, which is why the error status doesn't need to be returned.)

Comment: But, ignoring the question, I think it would be beneficial to complicate this a bit more rather than simplify, e.g., test for error and allow the caller to determine how the size is increased (such as when `* 2` is not enough or is too much if the final size is known). But, as pointed out already, then you essentially have just `realloc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `int` is not the good type for sizes. Use the correct one `size_t`
2. Try to avoid side effects (ie modifying the objects passed by reference) without special need.
3. Your code is potentially leaking memory. If `realloc` failes you loose the reference to the previously allocated memory. The integer referenced by `size` is also changed without the need.

I would implement it this way:

```
char **resize(char **arr, size_t newsize)
{
    return realloc(arr, size * sizeof(*arr));
}
```

And the caller function should check for the errors.

But what is the point of defining this function? This one only returns the return value of `realloc`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm quite new to C and dynamic memory, that's why I wrote working, but apparently bad code.